# How can I run the JVM with the -XstartOnFirstThread

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to run my first program in java using maven in intelliJ. But I'm having an error like below : "GLFW may only be used on the main thread and that thread must be the first thread in the process. Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread"
How can I work it out?

I was looking for the answer in the internet but could not find it out

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#createExplicitly. "Add VM options".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running a libGDX game on my Macbook with a M1 processor.

You need to run your program with the additional JVM option `-XstartOnFirstThread`.

Typically when you run it from IntelliJ you can create (or edit) a run configuration and add in exactly `-XstartOnFirstThread` as a "JVM option".

If you add it as a "program argument" it will not work. It's a flag for the virtual machine, and not the program itself.

The [link @CrazyCoder gave in the comment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#createExplicitly) of your question gives a good
explanation on how to do this in IntelliJ. It's similar for Android Studio.